# Using google maps for city transport tracking

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a non-commercial Android app for tracking city buses. An open API is used, which gives the coordinates of buses and route lines. About 15,000 users use the app every day.

I am currently using OSM as a map and want to switch to Google Maps.

Q: Is it possible to use Google Maps to track buses and how much will it cost? Is the free (200$ limit) plan enough for this? I do not plan to use any Google Maps API or services, I only need a vector map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no charge for usage without a map ID.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#mobile-dynamic

[image]